What does Android's default NFC anticollision protocol and subsequent data exchange logic look like?
I'm implementing NFC-A Type 2 Tag Emulation using an ST25R3916. This is as part of a device that will switch between reader mode and tag mode, and reader mode is tuned and works just fine. As I'm in development right now, reader mode is turned off, so it's only doing T2T emulation.
The ST25R3916 can be set to do automatic anticollision, where you just load in the NFCID, SENS_RES, SEL_RES_L1, SEL_RES_L2, and SEL_RES_L3. My values there should all be accurate for a T2T: NFCID is 7 hex digits, SENS_RES is {0x00, 0x44} for a 7-digit NFCID, SEL_RES_L1 is 0x04 for NFCID not complete and T2T, and SEL_RES_L2 is 0x00 for T2T. When the Pixel reads the emulated T2T, it gets all this information as expected and continues to go through the wake/sleep cycle.
Tag Mode (listen mode) has given me more trouble. I'm confident that my code operates as expected, as when I try to read the emulated T2T with another ST25R development board, it responds exactly as intended and with a fairly wide range.
But with a Pixel 6a (Android 14), it only completes anticollision and exchanges data in a very small physical area even though I can see that the device is detecting the NFC Field On and NFC Field off through a large area. When connected, though, it works reliably and will continue to read data and send HLTAs.
With a Galaxy Fold 4 (Android 14), it never even completes anticollision and always gets a Field Off at cascade level 2. With an iPhone 14, very similar behavior to the Fold, but the end user application will be on an Android so I'm not specifically worried about iPhone behavior.
What specific steps does Android NFC tag reading carry out to complete anticollision, and how do they differ between phones? I had thought that process (SENS, SDD, SEL) was universal.

See Host-based card emulation overview.
In particular: Nfc-A (ISO/IEC 14443 type A) protocol anti-collision and activation.
Or android.nfc.cardemulation, which may indeed be vendor-specific.
Your question is actually so broad, that you should better read AOSP source code.
